# Which was the X-Men comic where the mutant Santa Claus appeared, and what are his powers?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, episode-identification

I've heard so many times that Santa Claus is the most powerful mutant. But when did he appear in the comics, and what kind of powers does he have?

Comment: Article with video: [Santa Claus: The Most Powerful Marvel Mutant?](http://geekandsundry.com/santa-claus-the-most-powerful-of-marvel-mutants/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems he first appeared in Strange Tales #34 in 1955 (although I can't find a scan of it), and has [appeared a number of times since](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Santa_Claus_(Earth-616)/Appearances). (There are also [alternate versions](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Claus) of him in other continuities/universes.)

He first appeared in the X-Men comics, and was first called "the most powerful mutant ever registered", when Cerebro picked up on him at Christmas time in Marvel's [Holiday Special Vol 1 1991](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Holiday_Special_Vol_1_1991):

[image: Marvel Holiday Special Vol 1 1991][image]

He has [several powers](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Santa_Claus_(Earth-616)#Powers_and_Abilities), including longevity, the ability to fit himself and others through any chimney, fire resistance, levitation, altering his own or other beings' appearance, changing the size of other objects, teleportation, snow generation, the ability to eavesdrop on anyone and super strength (possibly just on Christmas Eve). He possesses or controls several magical artifacts and beings, like his sack which is a portal to another dimension, magical flying reindeer, and elves.

Comment: Pictures needed please

Comment: @Valorum Found one relevant one at least.

Comment: Perfection :-)))

Comment: @Valorum Even more perfect with the whole spread, like so ;)

Comment: STOP THAT BEARDED MAN *!*

Comment: Who's the guy flying next to Banshee?

Comment: @Valorum call Wonderella. She does kills/neuters him every six years, so I hear. I'd have to give you an IOU on the link to the specific comic, but she indeed locked up santa in the Disney Vault a while ago. Now it all makes sense.

Comment: @Kevin Sounds like something worthy of a new question!

Comment: He’s pretty great at list-making too.

Comment: If those are officially mutant powers, it stands to reason that power-absorbing mutants like Rogue could claim or copy his powers. Since he only seems to be really using them on Christmas Eve and doesn't really need them the rest of the year, he'd be a valuable strategic ally. Of course, the *real* question is whether Squirrel Girl could take him in a fight. Presumably, whoever wins, the results would be heartwarming.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite but not great at list-remembering, hence his incessant need to check the list

Comment: No super speed?